# Grails - Unit test controller that's using a named marshaller

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, spock

I'm trying to unit test a controller that's using a named marshaller. The controller looks like this:

```
def userByEmail(UserByEmailCommand userByEmailCommand) {
    render checkForErrorsAndExecute(userByEmailCommand) { UserByEmailCommand cmd ->
        JSON.use("complete") {
            [users: [userService.getUserByPrimaryEmailAddress(cmd.email)]] as JSON
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test I'm getting an exception saying `Converter Configuration with name 'complete' not found!`.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the named config in the test itself. For example:

```
given: 'register marshaller'
JSON.createNamedConfig('complete') { 
    it.registerObjectMarshaller(Map) { Map item -> item }
}

when: 'controller action is called'
controller.userByEmail()

then:
// assertion goes here
```

Comment: Is there a solution without holding the named marshaller code twice, in bootstrap and in the test file? Thanks